# The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to Espectador

Tags: java, arrays, object

I´m having problems with this part of the code, but I´m not sure why.
I´m struggling to understand objects, I cant find the error here.

[The butacas 2D matrix is created in main.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/alnwJ.png)

Comment: You should copy the code here, it makes it so much easier to understand and give the right answer. Next time feel free to copy here.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because of language differences I don't get the problem right I discuss what I've found out.

You had some kind of seats and viewers/spectators. The seats are placed in rows and columns like a 2D array. You have to iterate over this array and you have problems with it.

Speaking about arrays in java, they don't have `length()` method but `length` field, which can be accessed like `myArray.length`. You can further read about arrays [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html).

In your code you have defined butacas as some kind of `Espectador` object. It looks like `Espectador` doesn't have the method `getLength()` and neither can be used like an array with the brackets. (For example: `myArray[index]`)  If butacas is some other kind of object, then I cannot tell which method does it have for its length.

If butacas is a 2D array, your method should look like this:

```java
static void asignarButacaEspectador(String espectador, Espectador[][] butacas) {
    for (int i = 0; i < butacas.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < butacas[i].length; j++) {

        }
    }
}
```

Also please note, that we usually start the variable/parameter names with lowercase letters in java. You can find some basic naming conventions at [Oracle's site](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html).

If you have a different data structure for butacas please share it with me.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to only use espectador as an attribute and butacas was in the class already therefore I deleted the butacas attribute and ended up with this:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3ab4.png